# Hide the visible content before view the next content

Tags: jquery

When you click on the link with `id="viewers"` to view it's content and then, after it's visible, when you click on the link with `id="voters"`, `id="viewers"` will hide and then show `id="voters"`'s content. How can I do that? I've tried for myself but I didn't come so far :/ Here is my code:

```
$('#view_voters').click(function() {
    if($('#viewers').is(':visible')) {
        $('#viewers').slideUp('slow');
    }

    if($('#viewers').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#voters').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
echo '<div class="paddingbottom-10" id="voters" style="display: none;">';
    echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blog-viewers">';
        # content
    echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why check for the same condition twice? Just transform your 'if-if' code into 'if-else' one, as `visible` and `hidden` are the opposite conditions. Like this:

```
if ($('#viewers').is(':visible')) {
    $('#viewers').slideUp('slow');
}
else {
    $('#voters').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried that way to near solution - it didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Without your html is hard to tell but you can simplify and do something like this which is also more extensible.

```
var $panels = $('.panel'); // All your sections with class `.panel`

var panelSlide = function ($this) {
    $panels.find(':visible').slideUp('fast', function () {
        $this.slideDown();
    });
};
$('#voters, #viewers').click(function () {
    panelSlide($(this).find('.panel'));
});
```

Comment: This is more of an approach concept. I doubt this will work just like that. Without your html I can't say for sure.

Comment: Please see my edit in my question now. I added `panel` within the `class=""` before `paddingbottom-10` (`panel paddingbottom-10`).

Answer (score 0):

Set one of the elements to hidden, and set the other to visible.

```
<input id='view_voters' value='Toggle Viewers/Voters' type='button' />

<div style='display: none;' id='viewers'>
    These are my viewers
</div>
<div id='voters'>
    These are my voters
</div>
```

And then toggle both elements when you click.

```
$('#view_voters').click(function() {
    $('#viewers').toggle();
    $('#voters').toggle();

});
```

Full example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7akvT/2/

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't what I was looking for. If `id="viewers"` is visible and you click on `id="voters"` the first id (viewers) will be slided up and when it's fully hidden, `id="voters"` will be visible through `SlideToggle`.