# Close div when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using an old dhtlgoodies script to show/hide answers.
http://purple-mouse.co.uk/swift/about.php

It opens the answers and I've incorporated another script to change the background color of the answer while it's open.

Can anyone help me with closing one answer when an alternative question is clicked as the colors then don't look right.

I'd be happy for someone to tell me I've approached this in an inefficient way - always learning!

Thanks in advance, Mandy

Comment: can you share a fiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575656/hide-the-visible-content-before-view-the-next-content

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
    $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
        $div.hide()
    }  else {
       $div.show();
    }
});

   $(document).click(function(e){
       var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
       if (!p) {
          $(".dropdown-container").hide();
       }
   });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6BP/4)

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**Two solutions:  Both of them can be used but use it before calling your method to open an answer. Here we are closing all the answers setting css to hide.

> Pure Javascript

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

> jQuery

```
$(".answer").css("display","none");
```

> If you want to remove selected question also from jQuery. Call this before opening an answer.

```
$(".question").removeClass("active");
```